# Why 2 ExecStart are needed in systemd override?

Tags: systemd, docker

In the docker official doc (https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd), to enable remote/tcp API access you use an override as follows:

`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376
```

I followed the above and it works.

But why do we need 2 `ExecStart`? Does the 1st one serve any purpose?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' yes. hmm, should I delete my question?

Comment: John, I've undeleted your question as duplicates provide value to not only you, but also future searchers who find your post with its terms and eventually find the answer via the linked duplicate.